# Connecting via Remote Desktop to machine with Public network location?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

I have two Windows 7 computers connected on the same network via a switch. I'll call one "local" and the other "remote".

When I connected the remote computer to my network I chose the network location as `Public` (I'd prefer to have the remote computer's network location as public so it's not so visible on the network).  However, on the local computer I could not connect via Remote Desktop to the remote computer.  Changing the remote computer's network location to `Home` allowed me to connect via RDP.

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a way I can connect via remote desktop to a machine that has a `Public` network location?  Is this just a firewall change?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working correctly.  With my both machines connected via my LAN I still could not connect via Remote Desktop with the Network Location set to `Public` nor could I ping the other computer.  This was despite the fact that remote desktop access was enabled in the firewall.

However from within `Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules` I enabled the following settings:

```
File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)
File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv6-In)
File and Printer Sharing (NB-Name-In)
```

for both Private and Domain profiles.  The ICMP change enabled ping and the NB-Name-In (NetBios) change enabled connecting via remote desktop via the computername (i.e. via Netbios name resolution).

As far as I can tell my computer is still not visible from other computers on the LAN when browsing the network via Windows explorer which the behavior I wanted.